# Do you really need indexes on Foreign Keys in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I've seen various articles over the years indicating it's a good idea to index your foreign key columns in your SQL Server Database.  Our large database for the most part has indexes on every foreign key column.

In reviewing index usage in MS DM views though, many of these indexes show zero apparent usage (seeks,scans,and lookups).

Removing some of these indexes would save a substantial amount of disk space and do appear to have zero usage, but are there various internal and explicit SQL server operations and joins still using these indexes somehow that wouldn't necessarily show up in the MS index dm view stats?

I don't want to remove them and hurt performance if there is any chance they are being used.

Comment: This feels like you would get better results researching on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Zero usage *since when*? The index usage DMVs reset on events like service restart and even index drop/create. Make sure you observe for an entire business cycle before deciding an index is useless. It might only be used for reports that run at end of month or quarter, when the CTO is suddenly interested, it may be explicitly hinted somewhere, etc. And of course frequency of use is not correlated with how useful that index might be when it is used. Of course feel free to drop any of these indexes prematurely. But be prepared for fallout when the index is expected to be there and it's not.

Comment: Monitoring over several client databases over 6+ months, and most example systems are not restarted and have several months of history.  In the sampling I made sure the system had been running at least 60+ days or it was not considered as a good example of DM zero usage candidates.   I believe the DM View stats are probably reliable in the aggregate data I've collected and should cover for rare use examples.

I guess the question is still primarily the same one.   Do joins use indexes in a normal way that would that use be toggled as a seek,scan or lookup in the DM Views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need indexes on columns that aren't being used in operations where they're beneficial, like JOIN or WHERE clauses.

If you have indexes on **every** column, there are probably a lot of them that could be removed. You might even get a performance *increase* since indexes require maintenance even if they're not being used.

I'm not sure how much I'd trust the DM views. They're quite heavily filtered and might not show you what's actually happening, depending on where the objects live and what your permissions are.

Comment: We don't use indexes on every column but one of the DBA's previously added indexes on every foreign key column as 'best practice' recommendation.  Some of those were probably good additions but many are showing zero usage across many clients and I could gain back about 15% of database space by removing them.

We obviously don't have indexes on every column.   Indexes are evaluated on normal tuning reviews but the blanket add for foreign keys seems excessive and want to remove some of them but nervous that inherent operations like joins on foreign keys are indeed captured in DM View stats

Comment: It's really going to be a "try it and see" kind of thing. You might have an index that gets used once a year, but is the difference between a process running in 10 minutes or 500 minutes